# how to order by model function in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="player")
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def point_total(self):
        playerAchievements = PlayerAchievement.objects.filter(player=self)
        score = 0
        for p in playerAchievements:
            score += p.achievement.value
        return score

    def full_name(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

    def rank(self):
        print '---'
        players = Player.objects.filter(team__league=self.team.league).order_by(self.point_total())
        print self.first_name
        position = 0
        for p in players:
            position +=1

            if p.id == self.id:
                return str(position)
        return '0'
```

Nothing is processed past this line:

```
players = Player.objects.filter(team__league=self.team.league).order_by(self.point_total())
```

I also tried this but has the same effect:

```
players = self.objects.filter(team__league=self.team.league).order_by('player__point_total')
```

How can I order by the point total function so I can figure out the rank of each player?

Comment: Where's the `team` field in your `Player` model? This won't work, is this your actual code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `order_by` function only operates on fields in the database, so calling a function won't work.

What you can do however is [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/) the function with a `Count` aggregation across the `ForeignKey` and then `order_by` that:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

players = Player.objects.filter(team__league=self.team.league)
players = players.annotate(achievement_sum=Sum('playerachievement_set__achievement__value'))
players = players.order_by('achievement_sum')
```

Comment: I think he needs `Sum` rather than `Count`. And I think its `playerachievement__achievement__value` according to his code

Comment: This is more beautiful than poetry. Thanks @LegoStormtroopr . Thanks for the assist CésarBustíos

Answer (score 1):

You can't order querysets by methods and properties in django, you have to do the sorting by yourself in python.

```
players_to_sort = Player.objects.filter(team__league=self.team.league)
sorted_player = sorted(players_to_sort, key=lambda player: player.point_total() )
```

Comment: This is crazy inefficient if there are lots of returned objects (or lots of concurrent users), as it will result in all of the objects being sorted by Python, and each object having a database call to calculate the `achievement_sum` of each player.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr In this way yep, but, you can transform point_total to a cached_property, so you will avoid DB query. btw your solution is better.